# JavaScript addEventListener for 2 different inputs

Tags: javascript

I currently have an event listener that fires when input is changed like this:

```js
input = document.getElementById("inputfield1");

input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log("Do Something with inputfield1");
});
```

```html
<input id="inputfield1">
```

I now also want to add a second input so that the event is fired if `inputfield2` changes, too.
Can I just add it using an `OR` statement? Or should I create a whole new event listener for the 2nd field?

Comment: so bind another event to another element.....

Comment: Just define a named function for the event listener and use the same one for any element you like.

Comment: Or you can google the title of your question!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function f(element) { console.log(element.id, element.value); }
```

```html
<input id="inputfield1" onchange="f(this)">
<input id="inputfield2" onchange="f(this)">
```

or

```js
function f(event) { 
  var element = event.currentTarget
  console.log(element.id, element.value)
}

document.getElementById("inputfield1").addEventListener("change", f)
document.getElementById("inputfield2").addEventListener("change", f)
```

```html
<input id="inputfield1">
<input id="inputfield2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach explicitly the event handler for each element. Below there is a snippet, where it is shown how you can do this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.jsInputField')
        .forEach(function(element){
                element.addEventListener('change', function(event){
                    var elementId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id')
                    console.log("Do Something with " + elementId);
                });
       });
```

```html
<input id="inputfield1" class="jsInputField">
<input id="inputfield2" class="jsInputField">
```

**Update**

As Ram has pointed out in his comment, `NodeList.prototype.forEach`, is a method of `NodeList` that is supported from latest browsers (e.g. Chrome 51 etc.). For further info, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

In order you avoid to use the polyfill that is presented at the link above for cases that this method is not supported, you could make use of a simple for statement.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is a new method which is not widely supported!

Comment: @Ram Thank you for you comment ! I will update my post.

Comment: @Ram I agree but it is possibly not doing anything more than `Array.from(nodeList).forEach()`

Comment: However the main problem with this answer is that, it requires the anonymous event listeners to be registered at the same time within a `.forEach()` loop. One may need to create the other `<input>` element later.

Answer (score 0):

use querySelectAll() and for loop

```js
  function myFunction(){
    input =document.querySelectorAll("#inputfield1 , #inputfield2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("keypress", function() {
        alert("hi from"+this.id);
    });
    }
    }
    myFunction();
```

```html
 <input id="inputfield1">
    <input id="inputfield2">
```